# Angular SPA - REST API

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, angular, azure

I want to build a REST API for use with an Angular SPA.

My database is hosted on a SQL server through Azure.

A lot of online material I see when I search is for other types of databases or technologies.

I already have the database created.

How can I do this?

EDIT: I want to use ASP.Net Core for the API
but will use Angular to consume it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following:

**Architecture**:

If your Angular SPA is Angular 2+ ( Typescript ): Setup a new .NET Core 3+ Web API project with entity framework (since it is a relational database). I would expose all the endpoints using [swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) for .net and I would map all those methods on the SPA with a swagger client generator for Typescript.

If your angular SPA is not based on typescript, then I would not install swagger since the frontend is not strongly typed.

**Hosting:**

If you have an Azure account I would host both on Azure then you wouldn't have to expose your SQL Server to the web or create a VPN for that. Azure has also nice hosting for .NET Core projects.

**If you need to make it really scalable**

In this case, I would recommend you to publish this ASP.NET Core App building a container and have it running on Kubernetes or other container management server and have a load balancer to have the backend promoted with no downtime.